# System audio to Skype using Naudio

Tags: c#, audio, naudio, skype4com

I've been at this for a while, but made no progress. So this is my last resort! 
I am trying to send the system-audio (the audio I hear in my headphones) to Skype (making the persons in my call hear what I hear basically). And I thought I would do this using the Skype4comlib and naudio.

What I've done is to create a class which uses the `WasapiLoopbackCapture` and `WaveFileWriter` to write temporary data to a .wav file, and redirect audio using the SkypeSystemAudio.set_InputDevice method. But when I'm talking to somebody and I try to start recording, the person doesn't hear me anymore. I just go completely quiet and no sound is being played to the person.

I thought it would be best if I posted the whole class since it's easier to understand everything.

```
public class SkypeSystemAudio
{
    public NAudio.Wave.WasapiLoopbackCapture capture;
    NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice device;
    NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter writer;
    private Call CurrentCall = null;
    private Skype SkypeApplet;
    private const int SkypeProtocol = 9;
    private bool IsRecording = false;
    public string tempfilepath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\temp.wav";
    #region Public
    public void Initialize()
    {
        device = NAudio.Wave.WasapiLoopbackCapture.GetDefaultLoopbackCaptureDevice();
        Init();
    }
    public void Initialize(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.MMDevice device)
    {
        this.device = device;
        Init();
    }
    public void StartRecording()
    {
        capture.StartRecording();
        if (CurrentCall != null)
        {

            CurrentCall.set_OutputDevice(TCallIoDeviceType.callIoDeviceTypeFile, tempfilepath);
            IsRecording = true;
        }

    }
    public void StopRecording()
    {
        capture.StopRecording();
        if (CurrentCall != null)
        {

            CurrentCall.set_OutputDevice(TCallIoDeviceType.callIoDeviceTypeFile, "");

        }
    }
    #endregion


    private void Init()
    {
        capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture(device);
        capture.ShareMode = NAudio.CoreAudioApi.AudioClientShareMode.Shared;
        capture.DataAvailable += capture_DataAvailable;
        capture.RecordingStopped += capture_RecordingStopped;

        WaveFormat format = new WaveFormat(16000, 1); // skype wants 16 Bit samples, 16khz, mono WAV file
        //tried using the standard waveformat in the device object too. Didn't work though.

        writer = new WaveFileWriter(tempfilepath, format );

        SkypeApplet = new Skype();
        SkypeApplet.Attach(SkypeProtocol, true);
        SkypeApplet.CallStatus += SkypeApplet_CallStatus;

    }

    void SkypeApplet_CallStatus(Call pCall, TCallStatus Status)
    {
        if (Status == TCallStatus.clsRinging)
        {
            CurrentCall = pCall;
            pCall.Answer();
        }
    }

    void capture_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
    {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.Write(e.Buffer, 0, e.BytesRecorded);
    }

    void capture_RecordingStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsRecording = false;
    }


}
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working? I have no clues anymore what to do next.

Any help will greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol NAudio. Where can I get it?

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy http://naudio.codeplex.com/ If that's what you're asking =)

Comment: Another problem which I have with compilation of your class is classes Call and Skype. Give their declarations also

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy Google Skype4COM and download the .dll file. There doesn't seem to be any official download links anymore. Either try Nuget or as I said Google for the dll

Comment: One more question. How do you use your class? I created windows application, and compiled your class. How do you create instance of your class, how you join it with skype?

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy Call Init(); while you have skype running =)

Comment: I tried. Also I called StartRecording, and after a while called StopRecording. I received file temp.wav which has ugly noise. I assume that WasapiLoopbackCapture isn't properly initialized.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70410/discussion-between-yura-zaletskyy-and-tokfrans).

Comment: have you checked this? http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have actually done some something similar, but not using Skype4COM.

What I did was using "Virtual Cables" just like Sebastian L suggested, this way you can control whats going in and out off skype, the downside is that you need to install the virtual cables and configure Skype to use them.

[image]

[image]

The cables will appear in audio devices as standard input/output.

[image]

I have used these cables [VAC](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) and [VB cable](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is the way to go. Thank you!